# Can we read actual content or message published on Pub/Sub from this PubsubIO.readStrings().fromTopic(options.getInputTopic())

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe

Can we read actual content or message published on Pub/Sub from this?

```
PubsubIO.readStrings().fromTopic(options.getInputTopic())
```

I am trying to read the actual content from the `PubsubIO.Read` or can say the message published on my topic now the I want to send the message string to another server.

The problem is that my code, which is sending the data to the server, is only able to run when the build command is fired, not when a message is published on my topic on Pub/Sub. Since the code is only able to run when build command is fired I have got data `PubsubIO.Read` on my server, obviously this is because I converted the Object into a String.

Please tell me the way by way by which I can send the actual message published on PubSub and the way by which I can unwrap the `PubsubIO.Read` object.

```
public class CustomPubsubToText {
 /**
     * Options supported by the pipeline.
     *
     * <p>
     * Inherits standard configuration options.
     * </p>
     */
    public interface Options extends PipelineOptions, StreamingOptions {
    @Description("The Cloud Pub/Sub topic to read from.")
    @Required
    ValueProvider<String> getInputTopic();

    void setInputTopic(ValueProvider<String> value);

    @Description("The directory to output files to. Must end with a slash.")
    @Required
    ValueProvider<String> getOutputDirectory();

    void setOutputDirectory(ValueProvider<String> value);

    @Description("The filename prefix of the files to write to.")
    @Default.String("output")
    @Required
    ValueProvider<String> getOutputFilenamePrefix();

    void setOutputFilenamePrefix(ValueProvider<String> value);

    @Description("The suffix of the files to write.")
    @Default.String("")
    ValueProvider<String> getOutputFilenameSuffix();


    void setOutputFilenameSuffix(ValueProvider<String> value);

    @Description("The shard template of the output file. Specified as repeating sequences "
        + "of the letters 'S' or 'N' (example: SSS-NNN). These are replaced with the "
        + "shard number, or number of shards respectively")
    @Default.String("W-P-SS-of-NN")
    ValueProvider<String> getOutputShardTemplate();

    void setOutputShardTemplate(ValueProvider<String> value);

    @Description("The maximum number of output shards produced when writing.")
    @Default.Integer(1)
    Integer getNumShards();

    void setNumShards(Integer value);

    @Description("The window duration in which data will be written. Defaults to 5m. "
        + "Allowed formats are: "
        + "Ns (for seconds, example: 5s), "
        + "Nm (for minutes, example: 12m), "
        + "Nh (for hours, example: 2h).")
    @Default.String("5m")
    String getWindowDuration();

    void setWindowDuration(String value);
    }

    /**
     * Main entry point for executing the pipeline.
     * @param args  The command-line arguments to the pipeline.
     */


  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Options options = PipelineOptionsFactory
        .fromArgs(args)
        .withValidation()
        .as(Options.class);

    options.setStreaming(true);
    run(options);
  }

  /**
   * Runs the pipeline with the supplied options.
   *
   * @param options The execution parameters to the pipeline.
   * @return  The result of the pipeline execution.
   */
  public static PipelineResult run(Options options) {

    // Create the pipeline
    Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);
       try{
          /* sendData(PubsubIO.readStrings().fromTopic(options.getInputTopic()).toString());
          Logger.getLogger(PubsubToText.class.getName());*/

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json");
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType,  PubsubIO.readStrings().fromTopic(options.getInputTopic()));
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("server-url")
        .post(body)
        .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
        .build();
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
       } catch(Exception e){
           Logger.getLogger(PubsubToText.class.getName());
           System.out.print("error");
       }     

    /*
     * Steps:
     *   1) Read string messages from PubSub
     *   2) Window the messages into minute intervals specified by the executor.
     *   3) Output the windowed files to GCS
     */

    pipeline
        .apply("Read PubSub Events", PubsubIO.readStrings().fromTopic(options.getInputTopic()))
        .apply(
            options.getWindowDuration() + " Window",
            Window.into(FixedWindows.of(DurationUtils.parseDuration(options.getWindowDuration()))))

            // Apply windowed file writes. Use a NestedValueProvider because the filename
                // policy requires a resource generated from the input value at runtime.

                // call to the 
        .apply(
            "Write File(s)",
            TextIO.write()
                .withWindowedWrites()
                .withNumShards(options.getNumShards())
                .to(
                    new WindowedFilenamePolicy(
                        options.getOutputDirectory(),
                        options.getOutputFilenamePrefix(),
                        options.getOutputShardTemplate(),
                        options.getOutputFilenameSuffix()))
                .withTempDirectory(NestedValueProvider.of(
                    options.getOutputDirectory(),
                    (SerializableFunction<String, ResourceId>) input ->
                        FileBasedSink.convertToFileResourceIfPossible(input))));

    // Execute the pipeline and return the result.
    return pipeline.run();
  }
}
```

Comment: Your request body is always empty? is that you problem? Can you also explain more what you want to achieve. I have th feeling that you do the thing in the wrong order!

Comment: Just to clarify your question, you want to write a code to execute the 3 steps which are commented in your code, right?